# Give URL with ID in Angular UI Router

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router, angularjs-routing

I have a problem, when I edited data, my url not showing id example : `/answer/1 or /answer/2 or /answer/3` etc. Im confused because Im using **UI ROUTER** 
I'm a beginner use UI ROUTER angularjs. Can you help me ? What should I do ? Thanks

**My routing code :**

```
.state({
    name: 'answer',
    url : '/answer/',
    params : {
                obj : null  
    },
    controller: 'answer-controller',
    templateUrl: 'templates/table-answer.html'
})
```

**ng-click go to table-answer :**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="ListAnswer(data.item)"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i> View Answer</button>
```

**Pass params $scope.ListAnswer into answer-controller.js**

```
$scope.ListAnswer = function(data) {

    $state.go('answer', {obj : data});

};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's quite simple. Only one thing you missed there, otherwise your code is right.

```
.state({
  name: 'answer',
  url : '/answer/{answerId}',
  params : {
    obj : null  
  },
  controller: 'answer-controller',
  templateUrl: 'templates/table-answer.html'
})
```

**Now there are two ways to go over that state.**

//Html

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="ListAnswer(data.answerId)"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i> View Answer</button>
```

//Controller

```
$scope.ListAnswer = function(answerId) {
    $state.go('answer', {answerId: answerId});
};
```

**OR**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ui-sref="answer({answerId: data.answerId})"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i> View Answer</button>
```

Comment: {obj : data} --> send response to answer.controller.js and used them. If I use {obj : answerID} , how my response data can use or I should use data and answerID ?

Comment: Because {obj : data} is very important

Comment: Can I use two params ? like {obj : data} and {obj : data.answerId}

Comment: because {obj : data} to show table and I should to use that response

Comment: Why to send whole data in the params as you can fetch data with the params you passed. So just pass the unique ids and use them to fetch data in the controller.

Comment: Yes, i understand. Its working in my code, thanks :)

Comment: @SurjeetBhadauriya How will I fetch all  information from ID $stateparam . this is how I am passing ID `ui-sref="env({itemId: env.ID})"` . Now I want to show whole of env response in other state. From here I am able to pass ID only.

Comment: Yes, you can access it inside the controller using $stateParams(Also Inject it). Here is the code => $stateParams.itemId. This will give you your env.ID. And yes if you want to use it inside HTML then assigned it to $scope variable.

Answer (score 1):

Your state needs altering slightly:

```
.state({
  name: 'answer',
  url : '/answer/{itemId}',
  params : {
    obj : null  
  },
  controller: 'answer-controller',
  templateUrl: 'templates/table-answer.html'
})
```

Change your code slightly to pass along the id in the url of links:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" 
  ui-sref="answer({itemId: id})">
```

If you want to access the parameter from your controller however, you'll have to use $stateParams, so in this case, $stateParams.itemId

Comment: Thanks for your answer but can ui-sref give more than one params ?

Comment: Yes, you can pass more than one params in ui-sref. Here is an example: ui-sref="answer({itemId: id, itemName: name})